# Silverlight 5 hidden initParams

Tags: html, web-services, silverlight, hidden

I added Silverlight to a Web Page by using HTML, and everything work fine. But i want to hide my initParameters in the URl

This, how to look my page:

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" id="silverlightApp" width="100%" height="99%" style="min-height:600px; min-width:980px">
      <param name="source" value="ClientBin/My.xap?<%= URLTag  %>"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
        <param name="EnableGPUAcceleration" value="true" />
        <param name="maxframerate" value="20" />
        <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.0.61118.0" />
        <param  name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
        <param name="onSourceDownloadProgressChanged" value="onSourceDownloadProgressChanged" />
        <param name="initParams"  value="ActionID=215&token=8E4EB520-4E39-4127-B427-455C2549F019&email=hello@gmail.com" />
      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=5.0.61118.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
    </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe>





protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e) {
            base.OnStartup(sender, e);
            ActionID = e.InitParams["ActionID"];
            Token = e.InitParams["token"];
}
```

Now, my url looks like this:
localhost/MyServices/MyPage.aspx?ActionID=215&token=8E4EB520-4E39-4127-B427-455C2549F019

but i want to hide parameters and get something like this:
localhost/MyServices/MyPage.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may get additional parameters from a web service / WCF RIA Service.

Comment: I proposed not to use init parameters, but query those values from Silverlight application by calling a web service that returns the values.